# Calculate field using data from excel table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, excel

I need to interpolate data that I have in a excel file using data from an attribute table of a point feature.
I want to create a new field on the attribute table with the result of that interpolation. The problem is that my data is on excel and I don't want to join the excel table with the attribute table. I just want to use the data from excel table to obtain a result for my attribute table.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use map joins with field calculator. Map join won't add the fields physically to your table, rather, it is an in-memory join.

Right-click your layer in TOC > Click Joins and Relates> Join...

Then use Field Calculator to interpolate.

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing that the only way is actually to do a join